# How to count distinct values in a row in Excel?

Tags: excel

I've googled for an hour and still can't find the answer...maybe I'm phrasing it wrong...

Anyway, a have a single column with textual values and I need to produce a table of two columns, in which each row would contain a distinct value from the original column and the number of times it appears in the original column. Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: If you have Excel 365 check for `UNIQUE` formula and `COUNTIF` formula.

Comment: Or a pivot table would work in pretty much any version.

Comment: I seems that a pivot table should do the trick, but it doesn't - it produces just one column...

Answer (score 0):

Try below formulas.

**C3** cell `=UNIQUE(A1:A12)` 
**D3** cell `=COUNTIFS(A1:A12,C3#)`

For single cell formula use-

```
=CHOOSE({1,2},UNIQUE(A1:A12),COUNTIFS(A1:A12,UNIQUE(A1:A12)))
```

[image]

Comment: You can remove the nested `UNIQUE()` if you'd phrase this a bit different; `=UNIQUE(CHOOSE({1,2},A1:A12,COUNTIF(A1:A12,A1:A12)))`. For OP's sake I'd also include the Pivot Table option tbh.